# Проблема со значением возвращаемым функцией. javascript

Tags: javascript

Передаю в функцию данные на обработку, что бы в последствии записать результат обработки в текстовый файл. Судя по очередности срабатывания логов, понимаю что проблема в том, что значение не успевает вернуться, но не приложу ума как с этим быть. Очень нуждаюсь в совете.  Собственно сама функция:

```
function convertMe(polygonArray){
var toWrite = '';
var dataToReturn = '';

var polygon = JSON.parse(polygonArray);
var isFirst = true;
var printFeature = function (name, poly) {
  var out = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      'name': name,
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": poly
    }
  };
  out = JSON.stringify(out);
  if(!isFirst) {
    out = ',' + out
  }
  isFirst = false;

  toWrite = toWrite + out;
}
toWrite = toWrite + '{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [';
async.mapSeries([polygon], function (poly, cb) {

  var options = {
    coords: poly,
    precision: 6,
    rowMode: true,
    hashMode: 'extent',
    threshold: 0.2
  };
  printFeature('shape', poly);
  var rowStream = hasher.stream(options),
    a = 0;

  rowStream
    .on('end', cb)
    .pipe(through2.obj(function (arr, enc, callback) {
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var bb = ngeohash.decode_bbox(arr[i]);
        printFeature(arr[i], [
              [
                [bb[1], bb[2]],
                [bb[3], bb[2]],
                [bb[3], bb[0]],
                [bb[1], bb[0]],
                [bb[1], bb[2]]
              ]]);
      }
      callback();
    }));
}, function () {
  toWrite = toWrite + ']}';
  console.log('Внутри вызова '+toWrite);
  return toWrite;
});

};
```

Место ее вызова:

```
worldData.features.forEach(function(feature){
q.defer(function(done){
  var dataToConvert = JSON.stringify(feature.geometry.coordinates);
  console.log('Место вызова '+convertMe(dataToConvert));
  //fs.writeFileSync(currDir+'/'+outputDir+'/'+'cell_'+i+'.s2', convertMe(dataToConvert));

  i++;
  done()
   });
});
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Место вызова undefined
Внутри вызова {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"shape"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[[-56.0828202,46.8785071],[-56.0832065,46.8780553],[-56.0840219,46.877938],[-56.0843308,46.8776271],[-56.0848973,46.8777385],[-56.0852407,46.8776564],[-56.0858329,46.8777385],[-56.0865109,46.8773278],[-56.0874293,46.8769875],[-56.0878327,46.877146],[-56.0880559,46.8770697],[-56.0886396,46.8767118],[-56.0895236,46.8764771],[-56.0898154,46.8763011],[-56.0900643,46.8759197],[-56.0904506,46.8756733],[-56.0915664,46.8757554],[-56.0923045,46.8757437],[-56.0929568,46.8755618],[-56.0933002,46.8758024],[-56.0939696,46.8763656],[-56.0944245,46.8769054],[-56.0951026,46.8773689],[-56.0945619,46.8778089],[-56.0939868,46.8784015],[-56.0929483,46.8789295],[-56.0917295,46.8794399],[-56.0907767,46.8796981],[-56.0896781,46.8799797],[-56.0895408,46.8801029],[-56.0891803,46.8802613],[-56.0892404,46.8804549],[-56.0888112,46.88076],[-56.0883048,46.880801],[-56.0880044,46.8810533],[-56.0866397,46.8813232],[-56.0853265,46.8811354],[-56.0846227,46.8810357],[-56.0850347,46.8808069],[-56.084163,46.8808322],[-56.083258,46.8804314],[-56.0830348,46.8801791],[-56.0830434,46.8797333],[-56.0830863,46.8794399],[-56.0837043,46.8792757],[-56.0834468,46.8791994],[-56.0835841,46.8790586],[-56.0833266,46.8789706],[-56.0832665,46.8788239],[-56.0835498,46.8784308],[-56.0830348,46.8786948],[-56.0828202,46.8785071]]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"fb24ew"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-56.09619140625,46.8841552734375],[-56.085205078125,46.8841552734375],[-56.085205078125,46.878662109375],[-56.09619140625,46.878662109375],[-56.09619140625,46.8841552734375]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"fb24ey"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-56.085205078125,46.8841552734375],[-56.07421875,46.8841552734375],[-56.07421875,46.878662109375],[-56.085205078125,46.878662109375],[-56.085205078125,46.8841552734375]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"fb24et"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-56.09619140625,46.878662109375],[-56.085205078125,46.878662109375],[-56.085205078125,46.8731689453125],[-56.09619140625,46.8731689453125],[-56.09619140625,46.878662109375]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"fb24ev"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-56.085205078125,46.878662109375],[-56.07421875,46.878662109375],[-56.07421875,46.8731689453125],[-56.085205078125,46.8731689453125],[-56.085205078125,46.878662109375]]]}}]}
```

То есть сначала мне выводится Undefined из места вызова, а лишь затем уже результат работы (к слову верный и тот который мне нужен) в месте

Comment: Ну а что вы хотите от `async` ? Так и должно быть. Не используйте асинхронных операций и не будет таких проблем

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за ссылку, но я хоть ты тресни не могу понять почему тогда в логе внутри вызова он выводит значение нормально? return стоит после этого лога, в логе данные есть, в return нету.

Comment: Во первых - у вас функция `convertMe` не возращает значение вообще. Единственный `return` стоит в `callback` функции `async.mapSeries`, а именно `return toWrite;`. Во вторых, даже если вы напишите `return` для функции `convertMe`, у вас все равно не будет работать.

Comment: надо не консоллогами дебажить, а с помощью точек останова. наставь точек останова и пошагово выполни свой код. посмотри, как меняются все переменные (так ли, как ты задумал, меняются), посмотри на каком месте интерпретатор в консоли ошибку выдаст

Comment: @justyx, а мне казалось по ссылке как раз и объясняется почему return в коллбэке асинхронной функции не работает так, как ты ожидаешь

Comment: @Grundy я понимаю что наверняка подобными вопросами на тему асинхронности и тп, тут уже надоели. Но если бы я прочитал то что там написано и все понял, то согласитесь я бы не стал спрашивать у вас снова :) Если сможете подкинуть еще пару ссылок которые на ваш взгляд хорошо объясняют механизм колбэков буду только благодарен. Поверьте я умею писать в гугле js callback for dummies (или что то похожее), но если бы я нашел инфу которую понял я бы опять же не стал бы спрашивать снова )) В любом случае спасибо что обратили внимание на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо передать в функцию `convertMe` функцию (callback), которую необходимо вызвать при завершении работы асинхронной функции `async.mapSeries`.

Пример:

```js
function convertMe(polygonArray,callbackConvert){
var toWrite = '';
var dataToReturn = '';

var polygon = JSON.parse(polygonArray);
var isFirst = true;
var printFeature = function (name, poly) {
  var out = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      'name': name,
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": poly
    }
  };
  out = JSON.stringify(out);
  if(!isFirst) {
    out = ',' + out
  }
  isFirst = false;

  toWrite = toWrite + out;
}
toWrite = toWrite + '{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [';
async.mapSeries([polygon], function (poly, cb) {

  var options = {
    coords: poly,
    precision: 6,
    rowMode: true,
    hashMode: 'extent',
    threshold: 0.2
  };
  printFeature('shape', poly);
  var rowStream = hasher.stream(options),
    a = 0;

  rowStream
    .on('end', cb)
    .pipe(through2.obj(function (arr, enc, callback) {
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var bb = ngeohash.decode_bbox(arr[i]);
        printFeature(arr[i], [
              [
                [bb[1], bb[2]],
                [bb[3], bb[2]],
                [bb[3], bb[0]],
                [bb[1], bb[0]],
                [bb[1], bb[2]]
              ]]);
      }
      callback();
    }));
}, function () {
  toWrite = toWrite + ']}';
  callbackConvert(toWrite);// Вызов функции callback при завершении работы.
  console.log('Внутри вызова '+toWrite);
});

};
```

Вызов `convertMe` и передача `callback`.

```js
worldData.features.forEach(function(feature) {
  q.defer(function(done) {
    var dataToConvert = JSON.stringify(feature.geometry.coordinates);
    //Запускаем функцию convertMe и передаем функцию обработчик завершения выполнения
    convertMe(dataToConvert, function(result) {
      console.log('Место вызова ' + result);
      i++;
      done(); //вызвать done, только когда convertMe завершит работу
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Я уже сумел разобраться, к счастью, но все равно спасибо за пример как это сделать в моем случае, очень туго колбэки в голове укладываются. Хотя судя по тому что сделать все таки смог то прояснения есть :)